# Shell script for crontab entries

Tags: shell-script, cron

i was asked to write shell script to perform the following task:

update cronentry  from

```
\*/15 * * * * /bin/sh /opt/myscript/myscript.sh > /tmp/myscript.check.out
```

to

```
\*/30 2,4,6 * * * /bin/sh /opt/myscript/myscript2.sh > /tmp/myscript2.check.out
```

before edit take a backup of the cronentry

i have tried the following script and need to check if it will work or does require any modification - please help!!

Shell Script to update cronentry(backup before edit)

```
#!/bin/sh
crontab -l > my_crontab.backup

crontab -l | grep -v "*/30 2,4,6 * * * /bin/sh /opt/myscript/myscript2.sh > /tmp/myscript2.check.out" >*/15 * * * * /bin/sh /opt/myscript/myscript.sh > /tmp/myscript.check.out

echo "*/30 2,4,6 * * * /bin/sh /opt/myscript/myscript2.sh > /tmp/myscript2.check.out" >>*/15 * * * * /bin/sh /opt/myscript/myscript.sh > /tmp/myscript.check.out

crontab */15 * * * * /bin/sh /opt/myscript/myscript.sh > /tmp/myscript.check.out
```

Answer (score 0):

You wish to delete a particular crontab entry and replace it with another.

You may dump the existing crontab schedule to a text file using

```
crontab -l >crontab-old.txt
```

Assuming that you know that the existing crontab entry is *exactly*

```
*/15 * * * * /bin/sh /opt/myscript/myscript.sh > /tmp/myscript.check.out
```

(with no additional spaces anywhere) you may filter that out from the `crontab-old.txt` file using

```
grep -v -x -F '*/15 * * * * /bin/sh /opt/myscript/myscript.sh > /tmp/myscript.check.out' crontab-old.txt >crontab-new.txt
```

To add the new schedule to the `crontab-new.txt` file, you could do

```
cat <<'END_ENTRY' >>crontab-new.txt
*/30 2,4,6 * * * /bin/sh /opt/myscript/myscript2.sh > /tmp/myscript2.check.out 
END_ENTRY
```

And finally, you load the new schedule with

```
crontab crontab-new.txt
```

You now have `crontab-old.txt` with the old schedule and `crontab-new.txt` with the new schedule, and you have loaded the new schedule.

You should obviously *look* at the files in-between each step above to make sure the correct edits are made to them, if you are running this manually, or while you are developing a script to do it.

In a script, this may look like

```sh
#!/bin/sh

crontab -l >crontab-old.txt

grep -v -x -F '*/15 * * * * /bin/sh /opt/myscript/myscript.sh > /tmp/myscript.check.out' crontab-old.txt >crontab-new.txt

cat <<'END_ENTRY' >>crontab-new.txt
*/30 2,4,6 * * * /bin/sh /opt/myscript/myscript2.sh > /tmp/myscript2.check.out 
END_ENTRY

crontab crontab-new.txt
```

The `grep` command uses `-F` to match the given pattern *as a string* rather than as a regular expression.  The pattern contains `*` characters which are special in regular expressions, so using `-F` allows us to match the string without special handling of these.  I'm also using `-x` which forces successful matches to match across *a full line*, from start to finish, rather than parts of lines.

Also related:

- [How do I add/remove cron jobs by script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/363376/how-do-i-add-remove-cron-jobs-by-script)

Comment: Thanks for the input